# Cast char to char array or char array to char?

Tags: c, string, char, c89, concatenation

So let's say I have a char and I want to strcat() it to a char array in a single line of code. For [a non-practical] example:

```
strcat("ljsdflusdfg",getchar());
```

Or I wanted to do the reverse, what would be the appropriate function to concat or typecast strings, regardless of data type? Or perhaps there is some syntax I'm missing...

Here's an example. It compiles just fine but crashes.

```
char* input(){
 char* inp="";
 while(1){
  char c=getchar();
  if(c){
   if(c=='\n'||c==EOF){
    break;
   }else{
    strcat(inp,(char*)c);
   }
  }
 }
 return inp;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcat` treats its argument as a pointer to a nul-terminated string. Casting a `char` to a `char *` is just dangerous, and I can imagine no reason it would ever be useful (not to imply that you're stupid for trying it - everyone makes silly mistakes when they learn. That's why we're here.)

The reason is that it would interpret the single byte `char`, plus the extra `sizeof(char*) - sizeof(char)` (usually 3) bytes surrounding that `char`, as a pointer, which would point to... anywhere. You have no way of knowing where it points, since 3 of those bytes are beyond your control, and thus no way of knowing whether it points to valid data.

You might take this as a second approach:

```
strcat(inp, &c);
```

This time, you'd be doing better, since `&c` is an expression of type `char *` and no casts are required. But again, `strcat` assumes it's argument is a nul-terminated string, and since you have no way of guaranteeing a nul byte after your `char` data, this won't do.

The best way is this:

```
size_t len = strlen(inp); // this may already be calculated somewhere else
...
inp[len++] = c; // add c as the last character, and adjust our len
inp[len] = '\0'; // add a new nul terminator to our string
```

UPDATE:

Actually, I lied. The *best* way is to use the standard library function [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html), which appears to be doing more or less what you're trying to do. Truthfully I forgot it, but if this is a homework assignment your professor may not want you using `fgets` so that you can learn how to do it manually. However, if this isn't homework, `fgets` does exactly what you're looking for. (Actually, the third approach is well on its way to reimplementing `fgets` or `fgets`-like functionality.)

I would also add some other commentary on your `input` function:

1. `char* inp = "";` will point to read-only data. A flaw in the C standard (for backwards compatability) allows string literals to be assigned to `char*` types instead of `const char *` types as it (IMHO) should be.


   There are several ways to approach this, but the best is dynamic allocation. Use the `malloc` function to reserve some data, keep track of how much you've used in your function, and use the `realloc` function if you end up needing more room to store it. If you need help with that, I'm sure you'll be back here (hopefully not *too* soon) with another question. :)
2. `getchar()` returns an `int`, because `EOF` is defined to be outside the normal range of a `char`. In order to distinguish between any `char` and `EOF`, it's best to make `c` an `int`. Otherwise a perfectly valid character may signal `EOF`. Be sure to cast `c` down to a `char` when you add it to the string, though.

Comment: This looks the closest to what I want, but &c gave me a string of what looked like escape characters. The other solution is just too much code.

Comment: @Anonymous - The other solution is _the_ solution. The `&c` version is incorrect for the same reason `(char *)c` is. If you think the other version is too much code, welcome to C programming. :P (Actually, there is a fourth way, but I'm not sure whether or not this is homework, and I don't want to risk doing your homework for you so I'm erring on the side of caution.)

Comment: This isn't homework. I'm trying to understand C for my own benefit, but I just don't have that much time on my hands, and I find the process excruciating. What is the fourth way?

Comment: @Anonymous - I edited my answer. (And don't worry - I went through the same process. It won't make sense for a few months, and then one day you'll get it, and it'll all be downhill from there.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer- I'll look into fgets. I didn't know my input function was so bad. About your point 1- I'm not concerned with buffer overflows, and I don't know how to declare what in other languages might be called a "fixed length string", and I don't want to learn malloc unless it is the fixed-length string declaration function I'm looking for. About point 2- I thought getchar returns a char data type, which is a byte.

Comment: @Anonymous - It's not, it's mostly right. You've got the most of the components down. Your real issue is pointers and memory, and that is a _hard_ issue: that's the part of C that takes a while to make sense. Don't get disheartened. (And the `char` / `int` thing is a very minor detail.)

Comment: @Anonymous - `malloc` and `realloc` are for variable-length strings. A fixed length string is just a `char []` (not a `char *`), but if you declare an array (on the stack) in a function you can't pass it back to the caller, so you would need to take it (as well as its length, so you don't overflow) as an argument. Which is more or less how `fgets` works. :P

Answer (score 2):

```
strcat(inp,(char*)c);
```

That is trying to concat the contents of the memory at where ever 'c' (as a memory location) is until it finds a zero.

A better way is to create an empty string of whatever maximum size you think is reasonable, fill it with zeros and then just insert 'c' at the current last position

Comment: "That is trying to concat the contents of the memory at where ever 'c' is stored until it finds a zero." No, it's trying to concat the contents of the memory that `c` _points to_ (when cast up to a pointer). `&c` is where `c` is stored. But +1 for the better way.

Comment: That's what I meant I was trying to avoid the pointer word - but reading it agian it could have been phrased better, thanks.

Comment: If I hadn't +1'ed you already I'd do so. Avoiding the P-word is probably a good policy when starting out with C.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to concatenate a single `char` onto a string, you can use `strncat()` and specify the number of characters to concatenate as `1`.  But note that:

- The destination buffer must have sufficient space; and
- In C89, you must have an actual `char` object to take the address of (so you can't directly concatenate the result of `getchar()`.

For example:

```
char str[5] = "foo";
char c;
int ch;

if ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    c = ch;
    strncat(str, &c, 1);
}
```

In C99, you can use a *compound literal* and the second restriction does not apply:

```
char str[5] = "foo";
int ch;

if ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    strncat(str, &(char){ ch }, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because the *inp char pointer doesn't have any memory backing it up.  When you declared it to be char *inp = "";, you only gave it the address of an empty string.   If you had given the following declaration   char *inp = "abcdefg", then you could have written 7 chars to it before you overwrote the '\0' and got into trouble.

You will need to dynamically increase the size of the backing memory as you input more and more characters.  You will also have the problem of knowing when to free the memory so you don't get memory leaks.

Also, your strcat needs to have '&' before the c.

Comment: Then how do I declare a fixed-length empty char array, and why is the output so weird when something goes wrong?

Comment: If he had given `char *inp = "abcdefg";` he couldn't have written _any_ data safely to the string - it's in read-only memory.

Comment: This is not really true.  On some systems yes, but not globally.

Comment: Also for Anonymous - char xyz[50];  memset((void *)xyz, 0, 50);  or whatever length you want.  If the array is declared globally, it is a convention that it will be all zeroed out.  However, some compiler options will write a bad pattern in the space so you can check for improper usage.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are returning a pointer to a stack allocated array. This is undefined bahavior. Secondly, you are attempting to write chars into unallocated memory. Thirdly, the type of `inp` is `const char*` not `char*`.

You want something like:

```
char* input(char *dest) {
  strcpy(dest,"");
  while(1){
  char c=getchar();
  if(c){
   if(c=='\n'||c==EOF){
    break;
   }else{
    strcat(inp,&c);
   }
  }
 }
 return dest;
}
```

Comment: 1. He's not returning a pointer to a stack array, he's returning a pointer to a string literal, which is going to be in global storage. 2. It's not unallocated memory, it's read-only memory. 3. The type of `inp` is valid, although if you said that the type _should_ be `const char*` I wouldn't argue at all. 4. Your function is just as dangerous, if not more so, as it does no bounds checking (a much harder error to spot). If you want the user to pass in their own buffer, make them pass in their own length as well.

Comment: `char *inp = ""` should end up being memory on the stack. with some optimization it _may_ be put into global storage, assuming global storage EXISTS on the architecture he's compiling on. 2. inp+1 isn't explicit allocated by the function. 3. The type should be `const char *`. The only reason he isn't getting an error is because he's using a legacy standard. 4. While my function is dangerous, it is no more so than `strcat` or the rest of `string.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code crashes because strcat expects null-terminated strings for both its parameters.

If you want to concatenate a char, you need to first create a null-terminated string from it.

```
char c[2] = {0,0};
c[0] = getchar();
strcat(inp, c);
```

But **don't use strcat**, unless you can guarantee that the input string has allocated space for that extra character. Better to you strncat which also includes a parameter for the amount of space in the first parameter (the dest).

I recommend reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcat) first.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use snprintf:

```
char newString[50+1];
snprintf(newString, sizeof(newString), "%s%c", "ljsdflusdfg", getchar());
```

It's a simple solution, but does require that you roughly know how big the string is going to be ahead of time.

Notes: I use the +1 to remind myself that there needs to be room for the null termination, and snprintf is better than sprintf as it is given the size of the buffer to prevent buffer overrun.

Answer (score -1):

Cast char to char array?
It's just like saying you want to cast a char into string.
You just can't do that directly.
Instead of char, place it in an array (myChar[]).
Afterwhich, strcat it with your original char array.

Comment: -1 for wrong answer. You need to terminate the array with 0 for `strcat` to work.

Comment: @brennan: i have remove one statement of my answer to make it correct. Thanks for reminding me about the 0 thing.

Comment: I didn't downvote (I was about to but then you fixed it), but while you've made it correct, you haven't exactly made it clear or helpful. Someone who knows C can tell it's right, but someone who doesn't understand why casting a `char` to a `char *` doesn't work won't understand why casting a `char` to a string won't work. You kind of just stated a tautology there.