# How to pass string to a function in C

Tags: c

Suppose I have a string "hello". I want to pass it to a function

```
void fun(char *p)
{
printf("%s",*p);
}
```

```
int main()
{
fun("hello");
}
```

Example 2 :

**How do I pass a character to char * ?**

```
void fun(char *p)
{
printf("%s",*p);
}
int main()
{
char a = 'c';
fun(a);
}
```

Why is this not working?

How to pass a string to a function in c **without passing its address**

Comment: `printf("%s",*p);` -> `printf("%s",p);`

Comment: Second one : `fun(a);` => `fun(&a);` and **keep** the `*` in the print. Change the format `printf("%c",*p);`Read the dupe for explanation.

Comment: @0___________ help me with example 2

Comment: @0___________ `&a` cannot be used as a string because there are no terminating null-character.

Comment: @MikeCAT no need for the null char if you read my comment

Comment: in 'fun(a)' a is a 'char' and you don't dereference it while printing.

Comment: @thirdeye I want to type cast a character to character array ? Is it possible to do?

Comment: @0___________ I just wanted to pass a character to char [] is it possible?/

Comment: [Cast char to char array or char array to char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687587/cast-char-to-char-array-or-char-array-to-char) if this help.

Answer (score -1):

The code doesn't work because `%s` accepts the pointer to the string, but an integer is passed. `printf()` may think that the integer is the pointer, but actually there are almost no chance that the integer becomes a valid pointer.

`printf("%s",*p);` invokes *undefined behavior* because `char` is passed where `char*` is expected. You should remove `*` here. Also `p` should be `const char*` instead of `char*` to tell the compiler that the string is not modified.

```
void fun(const char *p)
{
printf("%s",p);
}
```

To pass strings (sequences of characters terminated by a null-character) without passing its address, you can put strings in structures and pass them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct str_container {
    char str[32];
};

void fun(struct str_container sc)
{
    printf("%s",sc.str);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct str_container str = {"hello"};
    fun(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do I pass a character to char pointer? Like my example 2

Comment: @AmanJain "pass a character to `char *`" is ambiguous. Do you want to pass a string or simply a pointer to a character?

Comment: my program generates a char which I further want to redirect to a function having char*\

Comment: I want to pass a string